# Controlling ceiling fan and light with a single pole switch using caseta for apple home control

Tags: electrical, wiring

How can I control a ceiling fan / light which currently is controlled by a single light switch and pull chains using a caseta switch to integrate with the home app on the iphone

Comment: Do you want to control fan & light independently? Or simply turn on/off "whatever parts of fan & light that are selected based on pull chains"?

Comment: What have you done? Can you demonstrate that your efforts have not yielded any results and that is why you have come to us?   Have you used the internet to search for   information   on the  product ?  
 https://www.casetawireless.com/  -  https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Controlling+ceiling+fan+and+light+with+a+single+pole+switch+using+caseta+for+apple+home+control

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: If you want to use one or more Caseta switches, you need to check if the original install ran a 3 wire cable to the fan for separate light/fan control.  To control a fan, you also need to make sure the switch you're wanting to use is capable of that.